# How to interpret the database file of Football Manager

Tags: file, data-files

Is there any way to view the default database file shipped with FM release, e.g., like the file "basic_people_db.dat" in "`<fmdir>\Football Manager 2012\data\db\1200`".

I mean, either by converting it to a human-readable format like spreadsheet or load it to some database directly...

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt it.

> If the DAT file is actually a generic "data" file, the program that
>   generated the DAT file is your best bet for opening it

Comment: yes, but the what is the "the program that generated the DAT file"?

Comment: Its generated by football manager. DAT file just stores data, the content could be anything.  Only FM knows what's in the file.  Chances are the file's content is encrypted anyway.

Comment: i guess your'right. any idea about the decoding method? like what FMRTE did?

Comment: A guy has done such thing once and stored the player dataset in kaggle.com. And how did he do that is very interesting for me too.